# Broker - Unable to cast object of type 'Java.Io.SerializableImpl' to type 'Java.Util.Date'

Tags: 2011, broker, cache-channel-service

We were facing Broker - `CustomMeta` error, when ever IIS AppPool Recycle is done or IIS Reset is happened. But unfortunately, this is not the case everytime.

Below error occurs randomly on few servers. If the error starts occurring, it will reach **`> 3 GB`** log size.

```
System.InvalidCastException (Tridion.ContentDelivery)
Unable to cast object of type 'Java.Io.SerializableImpl' to type 'Java.Util.Date'.
    at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.NameValuePair.get_MultipleValues()
    at XXXX.Broker.ComponentMeta.get_CustomMeta()
```

When I browsed through the google and tridion stack exchange, I come across the **[Unable to cast object of type 'Java.Io.SerializableImpl' to type java.util.date](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-java-io-serializableimpl-to-type-java-util-date)**. But unfortunately error is exactly same but suggested solutions didn't worked.

From there, I started my investigation through the website logs and cd_core logs. I see below error enteries on `cd_core.log`.

### cd_core.log:

```
2014-02-24 00:05:46,050 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.linking.PageLink key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:05:46,050 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com_tridion_linking_PageLinkInfo key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:05:46,050 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:07:36,283 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:07:36,283 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentation key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:07:36,283 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com_tridion_linking_ComponentLinkInfo key=null] was dropped).
2014-02-24 00:07:36,283 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.meta.ComponentPresentationMeta key=null] was dropped).
```

> **What would be the fix, to stop these errors?**

Answer (score 1):

> **Did not process cache event because communication queue size 256 was exceeded ([CacheEvent eventType=Flush regionPath=/com.tridion.linking.PageLink key=null] was dropped).**

Above error is giving a clue that `queue size is 256` and which has been exceeded.

### Fix would be,

Open `cd_storage_conf.xml` and look at the `RemoteSynchronization` entry

```
<RemoteSynchronization Host="127.0.0.1" Port="1099" Queuesize="256" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000"/>
```

Change the `Queuesize` to appropriate value, which ideally would be `> 256`.

### For Example:

```
<RemoteSynchronization Host="127.0.0.1" Port="1099" Queuesize="512" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000"/>
```